# Awaiting ActionBlock<T> - TPL DataFlow

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am using TPL DataFlow and an ActionBlock to create parallelism. The reason for using TPL DataFlow is because it supports asynchronicity, except I can't get it to work.

```
var ab = new ActionBlock<Group>(async group =>
{
    try {
        labelStatus.Text = "Getting admins from " + group.Gid;
        await GetAdminsFromGroup(group.Gid);
    }catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) {
        // Log exception
    }

 }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 });

 db.Groups.ToList().ForEach(i => ab.Post(i));

 ab.Complete();

 MessageBox.Show("Complete");
```

The message box is displaying almost instantly, although the ActionBlocks still run. How can I `await` until the ActionBlock is complete?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ActionBlock<T>` exposes a [`Completion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160304.aspx) property. That's a `Task` which completes when the block has finished processing everything. So you can await that:

```
ab.Complete();
await ab.Completion;
MessageBox.Show("Complete");
```

I must admit I haven't used TPL Dataflow myself, but the examples suggest that should be okay.

Comment: Excellent Jon, that worked. I was just watching a video on Channel 9 that also mentions the Completion property. For anyone interested it's here: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/TPL-Dataflow-Tour ... I'm a big fan btw, was a pleasure to have you answer my question :)